# Mechanism Permitting Proton Sponge Effect

Tags: ions, chemical-biology, protons, lipids

The proton sponge effect is utilized as a drug delivery method to release contents packaged in micelles (usually coated in PEG or another protective polymer) into the cytoplasm of a cell after being endocytosed.

The micelle is able to attract hydrogen ions (which attracts chloride ions) into the endosome, decreasing the internal pH of the endosome. Water also follows the inward flow of ions and causes the endosome to burst, releasing micelle and contents into the cell.

I am wondering how ions are able to cross the endosome lipid membrane in order to attract water molecules and create swelling. I am aware that endosomes may have membrane bound hydrogen ATPases, but this doesn't explain chloride entry.

Comment: Feels like this might be more bio.SE than chem.SE...

Comment: It's a mix of both. I felt chem.SE was appropriate because I am asking about ion and lipid properties rather than a larger biological function. Lipids, ions and chemical-biology are all tags on this site as well, so I can't see why it should be removed.

Comment: It is true that ATPases pump protons across a membrane, and ions such Na and K also need membrane bound protein pumps; Na+ out of the cell and K+ into it. The crystal structures of some of these are known. see Brookhaven data base PDB code 2ZXE or 1K4C for examples. I'm not aware of anion pumps but they may exist.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you for the references to the PDB structures, I will check  them out.

Comment: When I first read *proton sponge effect,* I thought of 1,8-bis(dimethylamino)naphthalene …

Comment: @Jan that's a pretty interesting molecule, I will read about it soon when I have time.